# Rollup build typescrit error 'Unexpected token'

Tags: typescript, npm, build, rollup

I have a typescript project which I try to build with rollup and @rollup/plugin-typescript.
The project builds except when I import the module "../src/lib/pages".

The **repo** for reproduction is available here: https://github.com/igorovic/mangoost

The issue occurs in the file: `cli/cli.ts`.

## The Error

```sh
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/lib/filesystem.ts (4:29)
2: import path from 'path';
3: 
4: export function WalkSync(Path: string, prefix?: string, options={ignoreDirs: false}){
                                ^
5:     let Files: string[] = [];
6:     let Listing = fs.readdirSync(Path, {withFileTypes: true});
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:5195:30)
    at Module.error (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9676:16)
    at tryParse (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9590:23)
    at Module.setSource (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9982:30)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18101:20)
    at async ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18155:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async ModuleLoader.fetchStaticDependencies (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18179:34)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/Users/gor00/DEV/mangoost/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18156:9)
```

## How to reproduce

Uncomment the lines in `cli/cli.ts`

```js
//import { pages } from '../src/lib/pages';
//console.log(pages());
```

Run `npm run build`

After a whole day searching everywhere I did not find any hint on what may cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I fixed my problem by using two separate `tsconfig.json` one to build the bundle with Rollup and another one to transpile the `*.ts` files with typescript `tsc`cli tool.

The main issue was to understand that @rollup/plugin-typescript configuration option `inlude` is not related to the `tsconfig.json` option include.
It's used for some internal mechanism I have not digged in.