# Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: typescript, svelte, rollupjs

I have a custom dependency which is a `.ts` file. It contains `enums`, `interfaces` and `consts`, I'm importing like so:

```
import type { inteface1, interface2} from "common";
```

This works completely fine and the compiler doesn't give me any errors.

If I try to do an import from the same dependency like so:

```
import { paths } from "common";
```

I get an error saying:

> [!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
> node_modules/common/types.ts (1:7)

Both of these imports are from the same file but for some reason trying to import a `const` or `enum` doesn't work and importing an `interface` works. The only difference seems to be that when importing `interface`, there's the `type` keyword.

rollup.config.js

```
typescript({
        sourceMap: !production,
        rootDir: "./src",
        exclude: ['node_modules/**']
    }),
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"],
  }
```

I'm running with the command

```
rollup -c -w
```

versions:

```
"@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^9.0.0",
```

The file I'm importing (`types.ts`):

```
export interface interface1{
    field1: string
    field2: string
}
export interface interface2{
    status: "OK" | "NOK",
    field3: string;
}


export const paths = {
    path1: "/path1"
}
```

Here's the package.json from the dependency

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "types.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Type imports are erased by typescript, so the compiler never sees it—hence no error is triggered. I suppose `common` is a .ts file?

Comment: @Terry Yes, it is a .ts file. Only contains bunch of interfaces and has no dependencies.

Comment: If you remove *Error: * from the post title, and use what's left to search this site, you'll find that this question has been asked and answered here many times before. One of those previous posts should be helpful in solving the problem.

Comment: Except I already did and tried every solution and they didn't work. Only one I didn't try is one where the issue was solved but they didn't tell how it was solved. Linking the one I could not try, also feel a bit lost with this current situation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435078/rollup-build-typescrit-error-unexpected-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, I was doing something incorrectly. After all kinds of testing, here's what finally worked for me:

I added a `index.ts` file in the root of the project which explicitly exports my needed dependencies like so:

```
export {interface1} from "./types";
```

Added a `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "strict": true,
        "module": "ES6",
      "target": "ES6",
      "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./dist/lib/es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
  }
```

Now when I run `npx tsc` command in the root, It'll create a `/dist/lib/es6` folders which contains the compiled javascript.

In the dependency project I modified the package.json to refer to the compiled javascript:

```
  "main": "./dist/lib/es6/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/lib/es6/index.d.ts",
```

I still get a warning saying this, but so far no errors.

```
(!) `this` has been rewritten to `undefined`
```

Answer (score -1):

Make insure you have correct extension of file. In my case, I am not give my extension to my js file that's why error is occure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33593793)